# Pattern for deferred attachment of EventEmitter event handlers?

Tags: javascript, node.js, eventemitter

There is a seemingly well-known problem with attaching event handlers after an event has already been generated. This is a problem mainly when invoking functions that follow the pattern of returning an `EventEmitter`, for example:

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

function    doSomethingAsync() {
    var ev = new EventEmitter(),
        something = null;

    // Caller will never see this event because its 
    // handler is bound after fact.

    if(!something) {
        ev.emit('error', 'Something is null!');
        return ev;
    }

    return ev;
}

var res = doSomethingAsync();

res.on('error', function(s) {
    console.log('Error returned: ' + s);
});
```

This will return an unhandled error exception, because at the time `error` is emitted, no handler for it is attached yet:

```html
sasha@peacock:~$ node test.js
events.js:87
      throw Error('Uncaught, unspecified "error" event.');
            ^
Error: Uncaught, unspecified "error" event.
    at Error (native)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:87:13)
    at doSomethingAsync (/home/sasha/test.js:11:6)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/sasha/test.js:18:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:124:16)
```

The only solution I've been able to come up with is to create an `EventEmitter` on the calling side, bind the handlers in advance, and pass it to the function:

```html
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

function doSomethingAsync(ev) {
 var something = null;

 // Caller will never see this event because its 
 // handler is bound after fact.

 if(!something) {
  ev.emit('error', 'Something is null!');
 }
};

var res = new EventEmitter();

res.on('error', function(s) {
 console.log('Error returned: ' + s);
});

doSomethingAsync(res);
```

This seems inelegant and messy, though. The only reason event handlers on asynchronous operations that are applied via the first method work at all is because the operations in question usually take longer to complete than the function does to return. That gives the caller time to apply the event handlers to the returned `EventEmitter`.

Surely there is a preferred pattern, idiom, or hidden bit of JavaScript or Node functionality to handle this case better?

I suppose one approach is to not use `EventEmitters` to transmit validation errors or other errors that can occur instantaneously, but simply return something else. But I still think that's not a solution to the essential problem; this model, widely portrayed in Node documentation and elsewhere, relies on the assumption that the async operation will take longer to complete than the time it takes to bind the event handlers after the `EventEmitter` is returned. Most of the time, that's probably true, but it cannot be guaranteed to be true.

That's why I think there must be a better way. If there isn't, that would make Node documentation on best-practical use of `EventEmitters` very misleading. Surely there is a better way?

Comment: What I suppose would be ideal is to have an EventEmitter queue emitted events until a listener for them is bound, and only emit them then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `process.nextTick` to defer event emitting after current call stack being executed. For your example:

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

function doSomethingAsync() {
    var ev = new EventEmitter(),
        something = null;

    // Caller will see this event because it
    // will be emitted after current call stack

    if(!something) {
        process.nextTick(function() {
            ev.emit('error', 'Something is null!');
        });
        return ev;
    }

    return ev;
}

var res = doSomethingAsync();

res.on('error', function(s) {
    console.log('Error returned: ' + s);
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you! The only question I have is: the process.nextTick() documentation says: "On the next loop around the event loop call this callback." While it appears to work, what is the explicit connection between event loop ticks and the full extent of the call stack required? In other words, while the initialiser function may need to finish before the event loop iterates, what guarantees that the subsequent .on() event listener attachment in the caller will finish in that same tick? I assume nothing...

Comment: @alex-balashov In node v0.11.x (and will be 0.12) `process.nextTick` realized through v8 microtask (same as `Promise` and `Object.observe`). Micro tasks is executed RIGHT AFTER current execution of current call stack (so in other words - in the same tick). So if you are using `process.nextTick` don't bother about loop iterations. Actually `nextTick` is very unfortunate name.

Comment: @AlexBalashov If you want to execute your code on the NEXT TICK use `setImmediate`. If you want just to add execution of your code to the queue - use `setTimeout`. Look here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ&index=7&list=PLEebiPdGgg6nRV77RHDNe0lXAN7ya3L_3. Th is very simplified explanation about event loop.

Comment: Any approach reliant on `setTimeout()` makes assumptions about how long the function returning the `EventEmitter` will take to return, and how long it will take to .on() the listener. While those assumptions are likely to be correct and everything will work just fine, I would like a method that is more formally correct.

Comment: `setTimeout` just adds your callback to the task queue (another names - message queue, event queue). It can't interrupt your current execution (nothing can except error throwing). When your call `setTimeout(callback, 1000)` it just guaranties that that callback will be added to task queue after 1s, but can be executed after 1 minute (if your task queue is so staffed). So it doesn't matter how long `EventEmitter` will take to return, and how long it will take to .on() the listener. As long as `EventEmitter` and `.on()` in the same call stack, `setTimeout(c, 0)` will always works.

Comment: @AlexBalashov But for your case `process.nextTick` is a best choice.

Comment: "So it doesn't matter how long EventEmitter will take to return, and how long it will take to .on() the listener."

I assume this holds true of `process.nextTick()`, too? If so, why is it a better choice?

Answer (score 0):

(A very late answer hoping that it would help someone )

Do not rely on process.nextTick() and it may not guarantee the subsequent events emitted (and a little messy things may occur down the road), the best trick is to extend your emitter and push the deferred events to stack and resolve it by FIFO. Pass a callback to the extended emitter and receive response
here's the working code,

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
const util = require('util');
const events = require('events');

const DeferredEventEmitter = function(next) {
   EventEmitter.call(this);
   this.defferedEvents = [];  // stack or cache those require deferred execution

   //resolve the events
   this.on('error', function(s) { 
    //console.log(this.defferedEvents)
    //console.log('Error returned: ' + s);
    if(next) 
        next(s)  //execute the callback if error
   })

   this.on('success', function(s) { 
    //console.log('Success!' + s)
    if(next)
        next(s)
   })
   
   //here add further events to be resolved
   //this.on('some_event', function().....

}
 //inherit and apply native event emitter to our 
util.inherits(DeferredEventEmitter , events.EventEmitter);  

// push to stack
DeferredEventEmitter.prototype.deferredEmit = function(name, payload) {
  this.defferedEvents.push({name, payload});
}

// resolve each deferred event (FIFO)
DeferredEventEmitter.prototype.broadcastDeferredEmit = function() {
if(!this.defferedEvents.length)
    return;
  while(this.defferedEvents.length) { 
    const event = this.defferedEvents.shift();
    this.emit(event.name, event.payload);
  }
}

// The caller
function   doSomethingAsync(callback) {
    var ev = new DeferredEventEmitter(callback),
        something = null, everything = "not null";
    // Caller will never see this event because its 
    // handler is bound after fact.
    if(!something) 
       //push to stack the deferredEmit to later resolve
       ev.deferredEmit('error', 'emitting because something is "null"!');  
    
    if(everything) 
        ev.deferredEmit('success', 'emitting because, everything is "not null"!')

    console.log(ev.defferedEvents)
    //now broadcast all deferred emits
    ev.broadcastDeferredEmit()
    return ev
}
//call function and receive deferred emits without calling for it.
var res = doSomethingAsync((res) => { 
    console.log(res)
});


//module.exports = DeferredEventEmitter ;
```

I hope this is what you're looking for.